# Wordpress API variables sent in post

Tags: wordpress, api

I did a quick search but couldn't find the solution here, forgive me if this has been asked before.

I remember a way to add vars in a Wordpress post by adding something like [gallery=22] in the wysiwyg editor... anybody know where I can find the documentation on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the Shortcode API - http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: Ahhh...  I knew it was something like that... Thanks!!